# How to remove two TXT records from the .onmicrosoft.com domain

Tags: dns, office365

I want to remove the first two `TXT` records from my DNS settings. Somehow there is no edit button here.

How can I remove these entries?

[image: Current list of records]

Comment: Any right click options?

Comment: None unfortunately

Comment: Please see this post(Remove a domain from Office 365):  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-a-domain-from-office-365-f09696b2-8c29-4588-a08b-b333da19810c

Answer (score 0):

The *.onmicrosoft.com domain is managed by Microsoft. You cannot modify these DNS settings of that domain.